# spring boot cloud kubernetes config not working for multiple pods

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am using `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all` dependency for reading config map from my spring boot microservices and its working fine.

After modifying the config map i am using refresh endpoint

```
minikube servie list # to get the servive url 
curl http://192.168.99.100:30824/actuator/refresh -d {} -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

it working as expected and application loads configmap changes.

**Issue**
The above working fine if i have only 1 pod of my application but when i do use more that 1 pods only 1 pods picks the changes not all.

In below example only i pod picks the changes

```
[message-producer-5dc4b8b456-tbbjn message-producer] Say Hello to the World12431
[message-producer-5dc4b8b456-qzmgb message-producer] Say Hello to the World
```

**minkube deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: message-producer
  labels:
    app: message-producer
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: message-producer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: message-producer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: message-producer
          image: sandeepbhardwaj/message-producer
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: message-producer
spec:
  selector:
    app: message-producer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**configmap.yml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: message-producer
data:
  application.yml: |-
    message: Say Hello to the World
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        enabled: true
        name: message-producer
        namespace: default
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: EVENT
        strategy: REFRESH
        period: 3000
```

**configuration**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class MessageConfiguration {
    private String message = "Default message";
}
```

**rbac**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: default # "namespace" can be omitted since ClusterRoles are not namespaced
  name: service-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to read secrets in any namespace.
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: service-reader
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: default # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: service-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you hit `curl http://192.168.99.100:30824/actuator/refresh -d {} -H "Content-Type: application/json"` kubernetes will send that request to one of the pods behind the service via round robin load balancing.

You should use the [property source reload feature](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#propertysource-reload) by setting `spring.cloud.kubernetes.reload.enabled=true`. This will reload the property whenever there is a change in the config map hence you don't need to use the refresh endpoint.

Comment: But if i have lots of pods running then this is not a good approach. I want all pods to pick the changes immediately. Is there any workaround.

Comment: You can use the reload feature in that case..I have updated the answer with a link.

Comment: Do you have ConfigurationProperties or RefreshScope annotation on configuration beans?

Comment: Any error you are getting in pod logs? The service account need to have RBAC to access pods and configmaps

Comment: No error on pod and having configurationProperties as well https://github.com/sandeepbhardwaj/spring-boot-kubernetes code inside this git repo for message-producer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206224/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-sandeep-bhardwaj).

Comment: Sorry my bad i wasted your time as well my bootstrap.yml had wrong name boostrap.yml